# LocalHost to Domain Name using Express in React using nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, dns, localhost

I build a nice React website for myself that's using Node Js and Mongodb on the backend. I finished everything and tested my mongodb atlas connection and everything is working fine on that side.

I was using Express to create a server, developing using localhost:4000. Now that I actually have a domain called let's say https:something.com using AWS amplify, I don't understand what modifications I have to make. Do I have to make Express listen to that url? How do I do that?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 4000
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

..... GET and POST REQUESTS

app.listen(port,()=>{console.log("Listening on port 8000")});
```

I've been searching a lot but I couldn't find anything useful. Or am I not supposed to be using Express? Am I supposed to do something like this:

```
app.listen(port,"IP");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything, the custom domain is for frontend, so you don't need to change anything in your express code.

Comment: But it's not working. When I go to https:something.com:port nothing appears?Or more specifically from which url am I supposed to fetch from in the front end?

Comment: backend URL doesn't change, it will be the IP same as it was before attaching a domain, have you enabled cors in your backend? check console for what error it is giving when you open your application url.

Comment: Cors is enabled in Express but not in Fetch API. It says:
Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:4000/color due to access control checks
You can also check it yourself => https://master.dx9uez6l1pinl.amplifyapp.com

Comment: Where is your backend deployed? is it on the same instance as your react app?

Comment: Yes. It's in a folder called server along the src and public

Comment: is the backend server up? Check it from postman, I guess your server is not up.

Comment: How do you check it?

Comment: http://<your ip>:4000/color - any get would work you can try this. also check if you are allowing traffic on 4000 port in the security group of your ec2 instance.

Comment: Weirdly enough, when I do localhost:4000/color I see the output in the browser but not in postman! I also don't know what is an ec2 instance, do I need to create one on aws?

Comment: so your backend code is on your local computer? if so it can't be reached from outside your computer, you need to deploy your backend server on the cloud then connect to that endpoint from your react app.

Comment: Yes it is on my local computer. I don't think I know how to deploy it to the cloud, amplify documentation is not super helpful

Comment: there are many tutorials on youtube, try searching for ' deploy express app on ec2" or "deploy node js app on Heroku". after you get the endpoint, test it on the browser then update your react app. then it would work.